# iPad Drawing Issue?

Tags: ios, ios4, ipad

We are trying to develop a ipad app that allows the user to draw on an image, and then save the data for later editing as well. Some issues we are facing given in the document,  http://bit.ly/dJgwhZ. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think you would greately benefit from looking at [this](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/GLPaint/Introduction/Intro.html) sample code; it is called GL paint. It does most of what you want to do, you just need to implement the photo as background and saving to the library.

Hope it helps!